# Multiple LED outputs on FPGA using Verilog

Tags: led, fpga, verilog

I made a simple 0 to 9 up counter using Verilog. The output is 4 LEDs which are turned on when their corresponding bit is 1. The code synthesizes fine, but on the FPGA, only one LED lights on and off repeatedly. The other three LEDs do not light up at all.
Here is my code:

```
module counter(
   input wire clock,
   input wire reset,

   output wire [3:0] o_number
);

reg [3:0] cur_state;
reg [3:0] next_state;

always @(posedge clock or posedge reset) begin
   if (reset) cur_state <= 4'b0;
   else 
    cur_state <= next_state;
end

// Next state function
always @(*) begin
   if (cur_state == 4'b1001) next_state = 4'b0000;
   else next_state = cur_state + 4'b0001;
end

 // Output function
assign o_number = cur_state;

endmodule

module display(
   input wire [3:0] inumber,

   output wire [3:0] LEDs
);

assign LEDs = inumber;

endmodule
```

None of the LEDs are broken as they all light up when tested individually. Clock has been adjusted so its period is around 2 seconds.

Please help me out. Thank you.

I revised the counter module. Here are all the files I used:

top.v

```
module top ( input wire clock, input wire reset, output wire [3:0] LEDs);
counter c1 (.clock(clock), .reset(reset), .o_number(number));
display d1 (.inumber(number), .LEDs(LEDs));
endmodule
```

counter.v

```
module counter ( input wire clock, input wire reset, output wire [3:0] o_number);
reg [3:0] cur_state;
always @ (posedge clock or posedge reset) begin
    if (reset) cur_state[3:0] <= 4'b0000;
    else begin
        if (cur_state[3:0]==4'b1001) cur_state[3:0] <= 4'b0000;
        else cur_state[3:0] <= cur_state[3:0] + 4'b0001;
    end
end
assign o_number[3:0]=cur_state[3:0];
endmodule
```

display.v

```
module display( input wire[3:0] inumber, output wire [3:0] LEDs);
assign LEDs[3:0] = inumber[3:0];
endmodule
```

top.ucf

```
NET "LEDs[0]" LOC = K12;
NET "LEDs[1]" LOC = P14;
NET "LEDs[2]" LOC = L12;
NET "LEDs[3]" LOC = N14;

NET "clock" LOC = T9;
NET "reset" LOC = L14;
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want the next state to change on the clock signal rather than * ??

Comment: It is changing at the positive edge of the clock.

Comment: You change to the next state on clock but you change the state of nextState on *

Comment: Would that be a big problem?

Comment: Maybe not, but doesn't feel right to me

Comment: I'm actually following a guideline which tells me to separate a FSM into sequential logic, next state function, and output function.

Comment: There is nothing wrong from a Verilog perspective. My guessing only the LED mapped to `LEDs[3]` is the only one lighting up. If that is the case, try slowing down your clock to 1/4 its current frequency. If that does not work, double check the mapping in your top.ucf

Comment: Oh, one other thing. Most FPGAs have a limited number of flops with asynchronous reset/preset. Since your code synthesizes correctly you should not have an issue, but you may want to consider switching to synchronous reset. Remove `or posedge reset` to make it a synchronous reset. I doubt the asynchronous is the issue, I believe it is the clock frequency is the likely the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a problem with the top module. I did not declare the wire that is used to connect the display and counter module.

Here is the revised top.v:

```
module top ( input wire clock, input wire reset, output wire [3:0] LEDs);
wire [3:0] number;
counter c1 (.clock(clock), .reset(reset), .o_number(number));
display d1 (.inumber(number), .LEDs(LEDs));
endmodule
```

The LEDs light up correctly according to each state now.

Comment: There should have been warnings or errors about it. Can you please compile with this declaration and without it and see the difference in compiler/synthesizer messages.

Comment: Actually, there were no warnings or any messages indicating this problem. The documentation says that when no wire is specified in the top module, a one-bit wire is automatically assumed. Hence, I got the result where only one LED was working.

Answer (score 1):

My guess the issue may be in using `cur_state` and `next_state` without indexes. Try

```
always @(posedge clock or posedge reset) begin
    if (reset) cur_state[3:0] <= 4'b0;
    else begin
        cur_state[3:0] <= next_state[3:0];
end

always @(*) begin
    if (cur_state[3:0] == 4'b1001) next_state[3:0] <= 4'b0000;
    else next_state[3:0] <= cur_state[3:0] + 4'b0001;
end
```

and

```
assign o_number[3:0] = cur_state[3:0];
```

and

```
assign LEDs[3:0] = inumber[3:0];
```

Note me adding `[3:0]` everywhere and changing `=` to `<=` in second `always` construct.

The goal can be achieved by much simpler configuration:

```
module counter(
input wire clock,
input wire reset,
output wire [3:0] LEDs
);

reg [3:0] cur_state;
wire reset_n=~reset;
assign LEDs[3:0] = cur_state[3:0];

always @(posedge clock or negedge reset_n) begin
    if (!reset_n) cur_state[3:0] <= {4{1'b0}};
    else begin
        if (cur_state[3:0] == 4'b1001) cur_state[3:0] <= {4{1'b0}};
        else cur_state[3:0] <= cur_state[3:0] + 4'b1;
    end
end
```

**Update:** It did not help - then first thing to do it just to assign `LEDs[3:0]` with `4'b1111` and see if all LEDs are lit.

Next possible cause of issue is `always @(*) begin` which is being triggered on change of any input wires for the contents `always` construct. The only event it happens when you issue reset and `cur_state` changes to 0, and thus `cur_state` becomes 4'b0001 and keeps this value.

**Update 1:** So you have LSB working, other 3 bits not working. You tested that all LEDs are lit when you write 4'b1111 to LEDs's wires. I think code is correct, there's something else being wrong. Consider the following:

- simplify changing from decimal to hexadecimal. In this case you will only have `cur_state[3:0] <= cur_state[3:0] + 4'b1;` without any conditions checking for state #10

  `always @ (posedge clock or posedge reset) begin
      if (reset) cur_state[3:0] <= 4'b0000;
      else
          cur_state[3:0] <= cur_state[3:0] + 4'b0001;
  end`
- consider what happens to `reset` during test. Are you sure it is steady low? Alternatively, remove it from the configuration at all:

  `always @ (posedge clock) begin
      cur_state[3:0] <= cur_state[3:0] + 4'b0001;
  end`
- synthesize my code above with only one module and `reset_n` to see if it does not work too.
- try using other LEDs:

  `always @ (posedge clock) begin
      cur_state[3:1] <= cur_state[3:1] + 3'b001;
  end`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't solve the problem. I also want to implement it using two modules, so simplification is not needed. I'm using Spartan 3 FPGA board, by the way.

Comment: I updated the answer. I think the cause of issue is `always @(*)`. You can keep two modules, but there should be no need to complicate first module with two always constructs. Implementation should be as concise and readable as possible - this is a goal of any programming language including Verilog.

Comment: I can't quite understand the last paragraph of your answer. Can you please explain it again?

Comment: I tried all your suggestions, but still none of it worked.

Comment: Add your new code to the question (but do not remove old). I can not guess what you tried. Did you prove that all LEDs are working by writing all 1s into output register? My last paragraph says that `always @(*)` seem to not perform what you want  from it. RTFM on what it does and, most importantly, when.

Comment: I proved that all the LEDs are working just as you asked. I posted all the codes that I used, so it would be great if you could have a look at them.

Comment: Good, If you would look into my code you can see that I use negedge of inverted reset. Please try this way. In my opinion your current `always` condition should cause *cannot match operand(s) in the condition to the corresponding edges in the enclosing event control of the always construct* error. Also explain how it does not work now.

Comment: I tried, but I am getting no error whatsoever and the code synthesizes fine. However, on the FPGA board, the LSB LED turns on after the first clock, then at the next clock, it turns off with no other LEDs turned on. _So only the LSB LED (LEDs[0]) turns on and off repeatedly._

Comment: I updated answer with update #1. Your latest code looks ok for me, thus you should exclude statement by statement to see when you start it working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. The problem was that I did not declare extra wire in the top module. Thank you.